# android instrumented tests on device delete app data

Tags: android, sqlite, testing, warnings, android-espresso

i'm developing an app via Android Studio (with all latest recommended updates) and install it on my device via USB for my own testing and collection of data (which is stored in Sqlite database). Normally, I run my instrumented tests on an emulator, but yesterday the tests accidentally run on the device (which was connected to the computer via USB for charging). After the tests, the app's data was gone: the database and shared preferences. It seems like the testing nuked my app to make room for itself.

Does anyone know how to avoid such a destructive and disastrous outcome?

Additional information:

I run the test from command line via: ./gradlew test connectedAndroidTest

When I browse my device's /data/data through Device File Explorer I only see directory for ; but when I browse on my emulator, I see two directories: one for  and one for -test. However, when I run the instrumented tests on the emulator, from time to time my app data is also nuked.

To add insult to injury, the test use in-memory database, so really, the db file should not have been touched at all.

Comment: You mean "Android Studio" and not "Visual Studio", right?

Comment: right! corrected. thank you.